# javascript snake game - how to move the apple?

Tags: javascript

I've wrote this simple snake game - the one where you use arrows to navigate the snake to eat apples (red circle). Right now in my code when snake eats (intersects) the apple its(snake) size increases by 1 block (10px). 
What I would like to do is: every time the snake eats the apple -> increase snake size -> move the apple to different position within the canvas.

inside the code I've marked the section where I think the code for moving the apple should go, but I don't know how to implement and what would be the actual code for that:

```
if (!this.objectCollide(myApple)){
      this.segments.pop();
    } else {
      alert("COLLISION!!"))
    };
```

here's the Full Javascript code:

```
var gameField = document.getElementById('gameField');
var ctx = gameField.getContext("2d");
var blockSize = 10;
columnCt = gameField.width / blockSize;
rowsCt = gameField.height / blockSize;

var block = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

block.prototype.drawBlock = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x * blockSize, this.y * blockSize, blockSize,
    blockSize);
};

block.prototype.drawApple = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
  ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 6, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.fill();
}

var Snake = function() {
  this.segments = [new block(20, 20), new block(19, 20), new block(18, 20), new block(17, 20),
    new block(16, 20), new block(15, 20), new block(14, 20), new block(13, 20), new block(12, 20),
    new block(11, 20), new block(10, 20)
  ];
  this.direction = "right";
}

Snake.prototype.drawSnake = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawBlock();
  }
}

Snake.prototype.setDirection = function(dir) {
  if (this.direction == "left" && dir == "right" || this.direction == "right" && dir == "left" || this.direction == "up" && dir == "down" ||
    this.direction == "down" && dir == "up") {
    return
  } else {
    this.direction = dir;
  };
};

Snake.prototype.objectCollide = function(obj) {
  if (this.segments[0].x == Math.round(obj.x / blockSize) && this.segments[0].y == Math.round(obj.y / blockSize)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
};

Snake.prototype.move = function() {
  var head = this.segments[0];
  var newHead;

  switch (this.direction) {
    case "right":
      newHead = new block(head.x + 1, head.y);
      break;
    case "left":
      newHead = new block(head.x - 1, head.y)
      break;
    case "down":
      newHead = new block(head.x, head.y + 1)
      break;
    case "up":
      newHead = new block(head.x, head.y - 1)
      break;
  }

  this.segments.unshift(newHead);

  if (!this.objectCollide(myApple)) {
    this.segments.pop();
  } else {
    alert("COLLISION!!!")
  };
  var collision = newHead.x >= columnCt || newHead.x <= -1 ||
    newHead.y >= rowsCt || newHead.y <= -1;

  for (i = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (this.segments[i].x == newHead.x && this.segments[i].y == newHead.y) {
      collision = true;
      break;
    };
  };

  if (collision) {
    clearInterval(myFun);
  };

};

var mySnake = new Snake()
mySnake.drawSnake();
var myApple = new block(Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width),
  Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height));
var myFun = setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gameField.width, gameField.height);
  mySnake.move();
  mySnake.drawSnake();
  myApple.drawApple();
}, 100)

var directions = {
  37: "left",
  38: "up",
  39: "right",
  40: "down"
};

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode]
  if (newDirection != undefined) {
    mySnake.setDirection(newDirection);
  };
};
```

And example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9ztn3vs/

Comment: myApple=new block(Math.random()*gameField.width,Math.random()*gameField.height)

Comment: Just select a random block that is not occupied by the snake already (just try randomly until you get such a block) and then set this block to the apples internal data. For making the snake bigger you just need to append a new segment at the end of its internal segment field.

Comment: @Jonasw your code works! the problem is that after snake eats the apple , new apple appears on different position ( which is ok) but the "old" one does not disappear. Any idea how to make old apple disapper?

Comment: @pawel are you shure?

Comment: @Jonasw yes I am. it looks like this now ( after 3 apples eaten) : https://ibb.co/nrYdLQ

Comment: @Jonasw Can you help me with this issue please?

Comment: @pawel no, im currently busy and lilezeks answer looks like a good starting point...

Comment: ok, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `alert("COLLISION!!!");` just do these two things:

## Increasing the size of the snake

Just add another element to the array at the end:

```
this.segments.push(this.segments[this.segments.length-1]);
```

## Moving around the apple

```
do {
    myApple.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width);
    myApple.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height);
    var colliding = this.segments.find((v) => v.x == Math.round(myApple.x / blockSize) && v.y == Math.round(myApple.y / blockSize));    
} while (colliding);
```

Disclaimer: it is not efficient. It will lag as the snake's length will increase because the probability of collision.

Comment: Afaik the apple in Snake is not allowed to spawn on a field that is occupied by the snake. Your code is simple and surely helps OP but it does not solve that scenario.

Comment: @Zabuza And it is what is supposed to do.

Comment: The function `this.objectCollide(myApple)` of OP does only check collision with the head of the snake `segments[0]` and not with the other segments. Also I think the question of OP also included "*How to increase the size of the snake after a collision was detected?*", so you only give a partial answer, but nonetheless it is helpful.

Comment: Now is edited to do a real collision detect. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @lilezek thanks for your answer! About increasing the size of the snake: it's already implemented in original code `if (!this.objectCollide(myApple)) {
    this.segments.pop(); ` so the `pop()` method is executed only if snakes "head" and apple don't collide.  And about the apple moving: I used this code `myApple.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.width);
    myApple.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameField.height);` and it works just fine the only thing is that the apple that snake ate does not disappear. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @lilezek do you think you could help me with the issue i described above?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know, this would be a separate question, and you should close this as solved and then open a new one describing whats your new issue.